# Including baseline measure as control variable for DV and IVs when testing the effect of change on change

Tags: regression, repeated-measures

I am attempting to run an OLS regression:

A cooking intervention resulted in increases in vegetable intake compared to control after 12weeks. There were no differences in motivation between control and intervention groups, therefore, these groups were combined. I would like to determine if changes in motivation resulted in vegetable intake.

**DV:** Change in vegetable intake (initial intake - end intake)

**IV: ** Change in motivation to cook (initial motivation - end motivation)

**CV: **

- age
- sex
- ethnicity.

**Questions: **

- Is OLS the appropriate test or should a repeated measures ANOVA be used?
- In either, should initial intake and initial motivation be included as covariates in the model?

Comment: Were the subjects assigned to control or intervention using randomization?  Also, do you mean there were no differences in motivation between control and intervention at the initial intake (i.e., presumably prior to when the intervention started)?  Even so, it seems strange to mix the two groups together - why not just analyze them separately?  The two groups may differ in their vegetable intake, which is what matters here.

Comment: And how did you determine 'no differences'?  If this was by statistical testing, you are assuming that the power is 1.0 in order to make that statement.